# Add iOS distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I am in an odd situation.

I have an older mac where my apple developer account is signed in. I have the iOS development and iOS distribution certificates there. However, I cannot properly archive my project for distribution because xcode is outdated, and I cannot update my mac because it is too old.
I do have a slightly newer mac available to me that can run the newest version of xcode, however, I cannot seem to get the iOS distribution certificate to be recognized by xcode.

Basically if I go Xcode > preferences > accounts > manage certificates. I need to see an iOS distribution certificate.

The certificate is in the project, but xcode only lets me add "Apple Developer" if I hit the + in the bottom left there. Where as on the old mac, I can add iOS distribution and other things.

Comment: Why not just generate a new certificate with the new Mac?

Comment: I don't own the app and don't want to mess too much with their certificates. I'm new to the apple environment but I guess you need to add the certificate to the keychain on the machine before xcode can recognize it.

Comment: You can export the certificate using the keychain utility on the old Mac and then just drag and drop the file into Xcode on the new Mac. You will need to sign in to your developer account in Xcode on the new Mac.

Comment: yeah I was able to just add it to the keychain by opening the certifications. I guess I assumed Xcode would look for the certifications in the project not somewhere else on the machine